# Using editText in ListView using ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I am using parse api for my application.I am getting a list of items from the parse and after getting the list I wanted to populate it in the listview which would contain the following things:

- ProductName(TextView)
- ProductQuantity(EditText)

After getting list user would feed the quantity of every product and this information will be loaded in the new activity for adding extra information and after that it will be submitted to the server back.
I am familiar with lists but confused how can I use edittext in the listview to feed quantity of each product.
Please guide me.Thank you.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Loaded edittext with productname but I dont know how to get the values in the edittext

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: It is containing nearly 200 lines. Should I post all the code?

Comment: I made an activity extending Activity,initialized listview there.Made an Adapter for adapting this listview and then a model class for list items.

Comment: P. gehlot,  Just create a custom adapter that has the textview and editText, then when a user wants to save the information they entered just use the ObjectID you got when you passed the adapter the position to save.  Let me know if you need some code samples.

Comment: Why edittext is not able to hold the values I entered into them when I scroll down?